# How to list all files of a partition on linux?

Tags: linux, filesystems, storage, mount, rhel6

I am running out of disk on my rhel box. I am trying to find *all* files in `/dev/sda2`. Do we have a command which can give *all* files (ideally, with size) in filesystem `/dev/sda2`?

```
/dev/sda2
31297508   28615356   1092292  97% /

mybox > df

    Filesystem 1K-blocks       Used Available Use% Mounted on
    /dev/sda2  31297508   28615356   1092292  97% /
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sven's answer did answer the literal question of 'How to list all files of a partition on linux?' but I think that the implied question is more interesting:  'How does one figure out what is filling up the drives?'.

I start in the root file system, and use the `du` command.  This tells me the 'top talker' of sorts.  I then go into that dir and do it again until I drill down.  You can also remove the `--max-depth=1` part, and it will break down each sub-dir in one go.  I find that output a little overwhelming, but that this is style thing.

In the following example the /etc dir is the fat one.  (I shortened the output a bit.)

```
$ cd /
$ sudo du -amDx --max-depth=1|sort -nk1
0       ./bin
0       ./lib
0       ./lib64
0       ./sbin
1       ./lost+found
1       ./media
1       ./mnt
1       ./.rnd
1       ./srv
7       ./root
40      ./etc
46      .
$ cd etc/
$ sudo du -amDx --max-depth=1|sort -nk1
0       ./cron.deny
0       ./crypttab
0       ./environment
...
1       ./wpa_supplicant
1       ./X11
1       ./xdg
1       ./xinetd.d
1       ./yum
1       ./yum.conf
1       ./yum.repos.d
2       ./csf
2       ./pki
8       ./udev
24      ./selinux
40      .
```

In the following example on the same box, I take out `--max-depth=1`:

```
$ sudo du -amDx |sort -nk1
0       ./bin
0       ./etc/alternatives/cifs-idmap-plugin
0       ./etc/alternatives/ld
0       ./etc/alternatives/libnssckbi.so.x86_64
0       ./etc/alternatives/libwbclient.so.0.13-64
0       ./etc/alternatives/mta
0       ./etc/alternatives/mta-aliasesman
0       ./etc/alternatives/mta-mailq
0       ./etc/alternatives/mta-mailqman
0       ./etc/alternatives/mta-newaliases
...
1       ./etc/services
1       ./etc/sestatus.conf
1       ./etc/setuptool.d
1       ./etc/setuptool.d/98netconfig
1       ./etc/setuptool.d/98system-config-authentication
1       ./etc/setuptool.d/98system-config-display
1       ./etc/setuptool.d/98system-config-keyboard
1       ./etc/setuptool.d/99authconfig
1       ./etc/setuptool.d/99kbdconfig
1       ./etc/setuptool.d/99mouseconfig
1       ./etc/setuptool.d/99ntsysv
1       ./etc/setuptool.d/99printconf-tui
1       ./etc/setuptool.d/99sndconfig
1       ./etc/setuptool.d/99system-config-firewall-tui
1       ./etc/setuptool.d/99system-config-network-tui
1       ./etc/setuptool.d/99timeconfig
1       ./etc/setuptool.d/99Xconfigurator
1       ./etc/shadow
1       ./etc/shadow-
1       ./etc/shells
1       ./etc/skel
1       ./etc/skel/.bash_logout
1       ./etc/skel/.bash_profile
1       ./etc/skel/.bashrc
1       ./etc/smartmontools
1       ./etc/smartmontools/smartd.conf
1       ./etc/smartmontools/smartd_warning.d
1       ./etc/smartmontools/smartd_warning.sh
1       ./etc/sos.conf
1       ./etc/ssh
1       ./etc/ssh/moduli
1       ./etc/ssh/ssh_config
1       ./etc/ssh/sshd_config
1       ./etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
1       ./etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
1       ./etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
1       ./etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
1       ./etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
1       ./etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
1       ./etc/ssl
1       ./etc/statetab
1       ./etc/statetab.d
1       ./etc/sudo.conf
1       ./etc/sudoers
1       ./etc/sudoers.d
1       ./etc/sudoers.d/waagent
1       ./etc/sudo-ldap.conf
1       ./etc/sysconfig
1       ./etc/sysconfig/anaconda
1       ./etc/sysconfig/atd
1       ./etc/sysconfig/authconfig
1       ./etc/sysconfig/cbq
1       ./etc/sysconfig/cbq/avpkt
1       ./etc/sysconfig/cbq/cbq-0000.example
1       ./etc/sysconfig/certbot
1       ./etc/sysconfig/chronyd
1       ./etc/sysconfig/console
1       ./etc/sysconfig/cpupower
1       ./etc/sysconfig/crond
1       ./etc/sysconfig/ebtables-config
1       ./etc/sysconfig/firewalld
1       ./etc/sysconfig/htcacheclean
1       ./etc/sysconfig/httpd
1       ./etc/sysconfig/init
1       ./etc/sysconfig/ip6tables
1       ./etc/sysconfig/ip6tables-config
1       ./etc/sysconfig/iptables
1       ./etc/sysconfig/iptables-config
1       ./etc/sysconfig/irqbalance
1       ./etc/sysconfig/kdump
1       ./etc/sysconfig/kernel
1       ./etc/sysconfig/man-db
1       ./etc/sysconfig/modules
1       ./etc/sysconfig/netconsole
1       ./etc/sysconfig/ntpdate
1       ./etc/sysconfig/raid-check
1       ./etc/sysconfig/rdisc
1       ./etc/sysconfig/readonly-root
1       ./etc/sysconfig/rpcbind
1       ./etc/sysconfig/rpc-rquotad
1       ./etc/sysconfig/rsyncd
1       ./etc/sysconfig/rsyslog
1       ./etc/sysconfig/samba
1       ./etc/sysconfig/smartmontools
1       ./etc/sysconfig/sshd
1       ./etc/sysconfig/sysstat
1       ./etc/sysconfig/sysstat.ioconf
1       ./etc/sysconfig/wpa_supplicant
1       ./etc/sysctl.conf
1       ./etc/sysctl.d
1       ./etc/systemd
1       ./etc/systemd/bootchart.conf
1       ./etc/systemd/coredump.conf
1       ./etc/systemd/journald.conf
1       ./etc/systemd/logind.conf
1       ./etc/systemd/system
1       ./etc/systemd/system/basic.target.wants
1       ./etc/systemd/system.conf
1       ./etc/systemd/system/default.target.wants
1       ./etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants
1       ./etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants
1       ./etc/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants
1       ./etc/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants
1       ./etc/systemd/system/system-update.target.wants
1       ./etc/systemd/user
1       ./etc/systemd/user.conf
1       ./etc/system-release-cpe
1       ./etc/terminfo
1       ./etc/tmpfiles.d
1       ./etc/trusted-key.key
1       ./etc/tuned
1       ./etc/tuned/active_profile
1       ./etc/tuned/bootcmdline
1       ./etc/tuned/tuned-main.conf
1       ./etc/udev/rules.d
1       ./etc/udev/rules.d/66-azure-storage.rules
1       ./etc/udev/rules.d/99-azure-product-uuid.rules
1       ./etc/udev/udev.conf
1       ./etc/.updated
1       ./etc/updatedb.conf
1       ./etc/usb_modeswitch.conf
1       ./etc/vconsole.conf
1       ./etc/vimrc
1       ./etc/virc
1       ./etc/waagent.conf
1       ./etc/wgetrc
1       ./etc/wpa_supplicant
1       ./etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
1       ./etc/X11
1       ./etc/X11/applnk
1       ./etc/X11/fontpath.d
1       ./etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
1       ./etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf
1       ./etc/xdg
1       ./etc/xdg/autostart
1       ./etc/xdg/systemd
1       ./etc/xinetd.d
1       ./etc/yum
1       ./etc/yum.conf
1       ./etc/yum/fssnap.d
1       ./etc/yum/pluginconf.d
1       ./etc/yum/pluginconf.d/fastestmirror.conf
1       ./etc/yum/pluginconf.d/langpacks.conf
1       ./etc/yum/protected.d
1       ./etc/yum/protected.d/systemd.conf
1       ./etc/yum.repos.d
1       ./etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo
1       ./etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-CR.repo
1       ./etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Debuginfo.repo
1       ./etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-fasttrack.repo
1       ./etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Media.repo
1       ./etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Sources.repo
1       ./etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo
1       ./etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo
1       ./etc/yum.repos.d/epel-testing.repo
1       ./etc/yum.repos.d/OpenLogic.repo
1       ./etc/yum/vars
1       ./etc/yum/vars/infra
1       ./etc/yum/version-groups.conf
1       ./lost+found
1       ./media
1       ./mnt
1       ./mnt/cdrom
1       ./mnt/cdrom/secure
1       ./.rnd
1       ./root/anaconda-ks.cfg
1       ./root/.bash_history
1       ./root/.bash_logout
1       ./root/.bash_profile
1       ./root/.bashrc
1       ./root/.cache/abrt
1       ./root/.cache/abrt/lastnotification
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/0
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/0/2
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/0/2/c
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/0/2/c/7
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/0/2/c/7/2
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/9
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/9/4
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/9/4/f
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/9/4/f/3
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/9/4/f/3/2
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/9/e
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/9/e/6
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/9/e/6/1
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/9/e/6/1/9
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/a
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/a/6
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/a/6/9
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/a/6/9/b
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/a/6/9/b/d
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/a/6/d
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/a/6/d/a
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/a/6/d/a/3
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/b
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/b/9
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/b/9/2
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/b/9/2/d
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/b/9/2/d/5
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/b/b
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/b/b/b
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/b/b/b/e
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/b/b/b/e/e
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/d
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/d/b
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/d/b/c
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/d/b/c/4
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/d/b/c/4/0
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/d/f
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/d/f/6
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/d/f/6/b
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/d/f/6/b/4
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/e
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/e/7
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/e/7/9
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/e/7/9/4
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/e/7/9/4/7
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/e/e
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/e/e/d
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/e/e/d/f
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/e/e/d/f/d
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/e/f
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/e/f/e
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/e/f/e/f
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/e/f/e/f/5
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/f/4
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/f/4/6
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/f/4/6/d
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/f/4/6/d/d
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/f/7
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/f/7/6
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/f/7/6/f
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/f/7/6/f/f
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/f/8
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/f/8/a
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/f/8/a/c
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/f/8/a/c/9
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/f/c
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/f/c/9
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/f/c/9/f
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/f/c/9/f/0
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/f/e
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/f/e/d
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/f/e/d/0
1       ./root/.cache/pip/http/f/e/d/0/e
1       ./root/.cache/pip/selfcheck.json
1       ./root/.cache/pip/wheels
1       ./root/.cache/pip/wheels/8d
1       ./root/.cache/pip/wheels/8d/05
1       ./root/.cache/pip/wheels/8d/05/e9
1       ./root/.cache/pip/wheels/95
1       ./root/.cache/pip/wheels/95/14
1       ./root/.cache/pip/wheels/95/14/9a
1       ./root/.cache/pip/wheels/d7
1       ./root/.cache/pip/wheels/d7/6b
1       ./root/.cache/pip/wheels/d7/6b/69
1       ./root/.config
1       ./root/.config/abrt
1       ./root/.lesshst
1       ./root/.pki
1       ./root/.pki/nssdb
1       ./root/.rnd
1       ./root/tall epel-release
1       ./root/.tcshrc
1       ./root/.viminfo
1       ./srv
2       ./etc/csf
2       ./etc/csf/ui
2       ./etc/csf/ui/images
2       ./root/.cache/pip/http/2
2       ./root/.cache/pip/http/2/3
2       ./root/.cache/pip/http/2/3/b
2       ./root/.cache/pip/http/2/3/b/7
2       ./root/.cache/pip/http/2/3/b/7/9
3       ./root/.cache/pip/http/f
3       ./root/.cache/pip/http/f/f
3       ./root/.cache/pip/http/f/f/f
3       ./root/.cache/pip/http/f/f/f/e
3       ./root/.cache/pip/http/f/f/f/e/a
6       ./root/.cache
6       ./root/.cache/pip
6       ./root/.cache/pip/http
7       ./root
8       ./etc/udev
8       ./etc/udev/hwdb.bin
11      ./etc/selinux/targeted/active/modules
11      ./etc/selinux/targeted/active/modules/100
18      ./etc/selinux/targeted/active
24      ./etc/selinux
24      ./etc/selinux/targeted
40      ./etc
46      .
```

All that is left is to `ls` the fat dirs and find out what is in there.

Answer (score 9):

```
find / -mount -type f -ls
```

will list all files like with an output similar to `ls -dils`.

```
find / -mount  -type f -printf "%s  %h/%f\n"
```

will just print the size and the name.

The `-mount` (or `-xdev`) option tells find to not descend into other mounted file systems (which `/` usually has at least a few of) and `type -f` makes sure only files and not directories or links are listed.

See `man find` for more info.

Answer (score -1):

```
cd /
ls -lR > lists.txt
```

list all files with directories

Comment: it will also list files on other partitions that are mounted under the given directory.